# multiple dynamic url rewriting redirect to 404 page

Tags: php, apache, url, web-applications, url-rewriting

I am doing a project with fetching data from database. I am used URL rewriting method. I was using rewrite method it will redirect to error page

Dynamic url

```
http://www.sample.com/?cat=kk
```

The rewritten URL

```
http:/www.sample.com/kk
```

the `.htaccess` file written for this URL rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?cat=$1 [L]
```

The .htaccess file also contain another url rewrite

```
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /?cat=$1&sub=$2&year=$3&page=$4 [L]


 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?cat=$1&sub=$2 [L]

 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?cat=$1&sub=$2 [L]

 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /?cat=$1&sub=$2 [L]

 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /?cat=$1&sub=$2&pag=$3 [L]

 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?cat=$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

The problem I am having is that when I access any page, it will redirect to server default error  page.

Comment: Try checking your `error_log` file for hints and then comment out all rewrite rules and enable them one by one until you find out which one is breaking things.  The last two rules in your example require a RewriteRule below them which I do not see in your code.

Comment: By "default error page" you mean a 500 error or 404? In a 404 error, what's the URL that it says is not found?

Comment: You need RewriteCond for each rule so that the rules are not being run indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say that, but your rewriterules are messy.

Always start from the most complex to the simplest one.

And you've forgotten one of the most important directives: `QSA`. I let you google for this ;)

Maybe what follows still doesn't work, but it's cleaner.
We need log files to know what's happening.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /?cat=$1&sub=$2&year=$3&page=$4 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /?cat=$1&sub=$2&page=$3 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /?cat=$1&sub=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
```